# Bug in jQuery Deferred Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred

The following code has a bug that the ....promise.then(result) is executing without waiting for the file read to complete:

```
doAsyncReadFromDisk = function(myReader)
{
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    myReader.onload = function(event) {
        deferred.resolve(event.target.result);
    };
    myReader.onerror = function() {
        deferred.reject(this);
    };

    var rgReceivedFiles = document.getElementById('gdeReadFromDisk');
    console.log('Selected file: ' + rgReceivedFiles.files.item(0).name);
    myReader.readAsText(rgReceivedFiles.files.item(0));
    return deferred.promise();
}  //  doAsyncReadFromDisk()

catalogFileParseCB = function(){
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var myPromise = doAsyncReadFromDisk(fileReader);
    //alert('Space holder to let file read finish!');
    myPromise.then(console.log(fileReader.result));
}  //  catalogFileParseCB
```

When the

```
alert('Space holder to let file read finish!');
```

line is uncommented, the file contents are properly available.  So the conclusion is that the myPromise.then(...) call is executing without waiting for the resolution of the deferred call.

This fails on files ~200MB (real) data as well as smaller files (test data).  Not able to locate the issue, I am inclined to believe that the issue is not

Wondering if someone can help identify the bug.  Is there a better way of doing this? We are guaranteed to read only one file at a time, but should scale data size of several GB.

Thanks for your time, appreciate etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `.then()` is a function to call when the promise is resolved.

```
myPromise.then(function() {
    console.log(fileReader.result);
});
```